# Interpreting logistic regression on from R.

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance

Thanks for clicking! I wanted to see the effects of certain medical conditions on the revision rates on patients undergoing a cosmetic procedure. The independent variables I looked at included: age, gender, BMI, opioid use, and tobacco use. However, the data from R came back with a confidence interval of 97.5%, which I'm not really sure how to interpret.

I was hoping to see if you guys could tell me what is statistically significant and not, as I know if it contains "1" it is not considered statistically significant with a 95% confidence interval.

Coefficients:

```
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -1.51018    0.01713 -88.178  < 2e-16 ***
age65-69       -0.15505    0.02258  -6.866 6.61e-12 ***
age70-74       -0.26931    0.02448 -11.002  < 2e-16 ***
age75-79       -0.32874    0.02738 -12.007  < 2e-16 ***
age80-84       -0.49668    0.03500 -14.189  < 2e-16 ***
age85 and over -0.79847    0.05436 -14.690  < 2e-16 ***
ageUnknown     -0.03244    0.09429  -0.344 0.730809    
genderm        -0.23293    0.01644 -14.170  < 2e-16 ***
genderu              NA         NA      NA       NA    
rvBMI1924       0.18884    0.05381   3.509 0.000449 ***
rvBMI19         0.03693    0.06276   0.589 0.556180    
rvBMI2529       0.14927    0.04288   3.481 0.000499 ***
rvBMI3039       0.16774    0.02398   6.996 2.64e-12 ***
rvBMI4070      -0.02288    0.03211  -0.713 0.476112    
rvOPIOIDx       0.26913    0.02333  11.534  < 2e-16 ***
rTOBACCO        0.17444    0.01725  10.112  < 2e-16 ***
```

Odds Ratios and Confidence Intervals

### e^x Odds Ratios and Confidence Intervals:

```
                  OR     2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept)    0.2208693 0.2135647 0.2283947
age65-69       0.8563707 0.8192145 0.8950439
age70-74       0.7639066 0.7280241 0.8013475
age75-79       0.7198272 0.6820873 0.7593701
age80-84       0.6085462 0.5679571 0.6514989
age85 and over 0.4500169 0.4039770 0.4999691
ageUnknown     0.9680797 0.8019472 1.1608872
genderm        0.7922068 0.7670642 0.8181202
genderu               NA        NA        NA
rvBMI1924      1.2078449 1.0858130 1.3408564
rvBMI19        1.0376234 0.9161443 1.1717466
rvBMI2529      1.1609823 1.0666899 1.2619630
rvBMI3039      1.1826343 1.1281589 1.2393463
rvBMI4070      0.9773826 0.9174563 1.0405077
rvOPIOIDx      1.3088252 1.2501521 1.3698998
rTOBACCO       1.1905759 1.1509756 1.2315022
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not 97.5% CI, that's actually 95%. If you cut out totally 5%, in a two-tailed test, the lower bound is at the 2.5 percentile and the upper bound is the 97.5 percentile; 2.5% from each side. So, for instance, the OR and 95%CI for age65-69 is just 0.856, 95%CI: 0.819, 0.895.

Also, because some of your independent variables are categorical of nature, it's also a good practice to check if the whole set of age dummies are significant before diving into their individual p-value. To learn more on how to test them as a group, look up "log likelihood ratio test".

It's also probably not a good idea to use BMI > 70 as your reference group.

Comment: That's right, I apologize for the stupidity on my part. Is the Pr > z above on the top portion the respective p-value for the variables?

Comment: Yes, that's how R calls p-value.